# Microsoft Identity Custom User, Role, Claim Inheritance

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, usermanager

Hi guys i'am trying to inherit from the standard AspNet tables.

My intention was to use Guid as Primary key and extendig the basic AspNetUser
with some Properties. Furthermore I wanted to rename the table names.

Right now it is like:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{

    public User() { }

    public User(string userName)
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
    }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, Guid> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
 }
```

My DbContext looks like this:

```
 public class CustomDBContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{

     public static CustomDBContext Create()
    {
        return new CustomDBContext();
    }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole>>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>>().ToTable("Users");

    }
}
```

Unfortunately when Iam trying to generate my Migration. I get that error:

> The type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole`2[System.Guid,Easy1WebAPIData.Models.UserRole]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

Any ideas ? Best regards!

Comment: here you have a post to do what you ask. You can translate the page into English or follow the photos: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442819/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-modificar-el-c%c3%b3digo-base-que-me-proporciona-microsoft-aspnetcore-ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you just need to map your extended models in the `OnModelCreating` method. I am doing the following on a project of mine and it is working well with migrations.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> { }
public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }
public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<Guid, CustomUserRole> { }

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, Guid, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    }
}
```

Also, if you're using Guid's for keys, it is very common for you to set the Id in the constructor of the objects.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked! thx to @Phil Thomas

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("EmailAddress");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().Property(r => r.UserId).HasColumnName("UserID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().Property(r => r.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleID");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().Property(r => r.UserId).HasColumnName("UserID");

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimID");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasKey<Guid>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Id).HasColumnName("RoleID");

        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```